# how to handle call to flask func from jinja forloop using jquery

Tags: jquery, jinja2

I want to handle the routing of calls to flask func in the loop in jinja template through jquery

```
<div id="tab1" class="tab active">
{% for example in examples %}
<a href="#">
    <span id="example_id" style="display:none">{{ example.example_id }}</span>
    <span id="example_name" style="display:none">{{ example.name }}</span>
    <span class="example" id="handleEx"><a href="#">{{ example.text}}</a></span>
 </a>
</div>
```

Below is jquery code I have but it only works for first element. Nothing happens when I click the next elements.

```
$('#handleEx').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
      event.stopPropagation();
      console.log("handle clicked");
      $.get( "/handleEx/" + $('#example_id').text() + "/" + $('#example_name').text())
        .done(function(data) {
          console.log('handled ok');
        });
    });
});
```

How can I handle triggers from  next elements? Also, how I do make sure I'm reading values of example_id and example_name of next consecutive elements and not the same one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.linkClick').click(function(){
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log("handle clicked");
  $.get( "/handleEx/" + $(this).closest("div").find("span[name='example_id']").html() + "/" + $(this).closest("div").find("span[name='example_name']").html())
    .done(function(data) {
      console.log('handled ok');
    });
});



<div id="tab1" class="tab active">
    {% for example in examples %}
    <a href="#">
        <span name="example_id" style="display:none">{{ example.example_id }}</span>
        <span name="example_name" style="display:none">{{ example.name }}</span>
        <span class="example" name="handleEx"><a href="#" class="linkClick">{{ example.text}}</a></span>
     </a>
    </div>
```

In one page id should be unique this is the standard. So you can use name as multiple times but id shouldn't.

Comment: Click on next elements seems to be ok but I'm getting this error -Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined, while reading example_id and example_name.

Comment: Ok, let me check again

Comment: @jas I have updated the js & html code and added .linkClick class in the tag <a>. You can check it. Thanks

Comment: There was one small issue. $(this).closest("div") it still couldn't find those names but once I changed to  $(this).closest("li"), it is working fine. Thanks!

Comment: @jas thanks. But I couldn't find your li tags in your html code. Take closest element for getting the  example_id & example_name. I found there example_id & example_name(tags) are available inside the <a> and whole things are inside the <div>. So you can take closest <a> or <div> but <li> I couldn't find here.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I didn't realise I had simplified it for asking question, but my actual html is little differenct. But, I got your point and it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

when you call  `$('#handleEx')` , Jquery only return first element. So you can call by class `$('.handleEx')`

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks!